# Csv reader misinterprets quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

When I try reading my string with csv reader the output I get converts the json string to
`'{filter":"freeinternet"', 'region:"178307"}"'` which needs to stay

`"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}"`

This is what I've tried. I've even tried adding quotechar, escapechar, and trying different versions, but it results in incorrect results

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

s = u"""url,forgeresponsetype,identifiers,metadata,partitionkey,sortkey,expirationdate,lastmodifieddate,redirectkey,siteid,locale,type,update_date
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23"""



f = StringIO(s)

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', escapechar = '\\')
xd =  [row for row in reader]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `u` is for unicode (its just a relic from python 2). Make `s` an `r` string to keep python literal escapes. `s = r"""url,..."""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is, manipulate the input string to have different quote characters for the file and for dictionary data.

For example, use `'` as a quote character for input and keep `"` as a quote character for your JSON/dictionary values.

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
from io import StringIO

s = """url,forgeresponsetype,identifiers,metadata,partitionkey,sortkey,expirationdate,lastmodifieddate,redirectkey,siteid,locale,type,update_date
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23"""


f = StringIO(s.replace(',"{', ',\'{').replace('}",', '}\','))

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar = '\'')
pprint([row for row in reader])
```

The line `s.replace(',"{', ',\'{').replace('}",', '}\',')` replaces `"` quote character with `'` and then we are using that in `csv.reader`'s argument.

Note: It'll work as long as there are no nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

yes,it is because the `csv.reader` in Python treats the backslash character `\` as an escape character, and the JSON string in your CSV data has backslashes that need to be preserved

check this out :

```
import csv
import json
from io import StringIO

s = u"""url,forgeresponsetype,identifiers,metadata,partitionkey,sortkey,expirationdate,lastmodifieddate,redirectkey,siteid,locale,type,update_date
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23
https://www.expedia.com/Seattle-Hotels.d178307.Travel-Guide-Hotels,MOVED_PERMANENTLY,"{\"filter\":\"freeinternet\",\"region\":\"178307\"}",,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME.494647,1.en_US.filter:freeinternet.region:178307,1696746399,2023-06-18T06:26:40.521Z,,1,en_US,HOTEL_DESTINATION_THEME,21/06/23"""

f = StringIO(s)

reader = csv.DictReader(f)
rows = [row for row in reader]

print(json.dumps(rows, indent=2))
```

Comment: Please check the output, it is the same as the OP's code, as the escaped quotes are still being counted as quote characters.

Comment: I am getting `JSONDecodeError`, not sure about the issue, but copying and pasting your code is not working for me.